# I have a list of object. I want to show 8 items in the first row. If length of list is more than 8 then add one show more button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting list of object in `categoryData`

```
{this.props.categoryData.map((data) => (
              <div class=" p-0" style={{ width: "12%" }}>
                <div class="th-cat-link">
                  <img
                    alt=" "
                    src={data.photo_desktop}
                    width="50"
                    class="fluid-image"
                  />
                  <p class="th-cat-name">{data.package_category_name}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
```

How to add Show more on 8th position if the length of list exceeds 8. the remaining will show up in next row upon clicking `show more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works for me

```
state = {
    isMore: false,
  };
  handleMoreTheme = () => {
    let moreClicked = this.state.isMore;
    this.props.handleMore(!moreClicked);
  };
render() {
    
    var allActivity = (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.categoryData.map((data) => (
          <div class=" p-0" style={{ width: "11.11%" }}>
            <div class="th-cat-link">
              <img
                alt=" "
                src={data.photo_desktop}
                width="50"
                class="fluid-image"
              />
              <p class="th-cat-name">{data.package_category_name}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    var lessActivity = (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.categoryData.slice(0, 8).map((data) => (
          <div class=" p-0" style={{ width: "11.11%" }}>
            <div class="th-cat-link">
              <img
                alt=" "
                src={data.photo_desktop}
                width="50"
                class="fluid-image"
              />
              <p class="th-cat-name">{data.package_category_name}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    return (
      
          <div
            class="row">
            {this.state.isMore ? allActivity : lessActivity}
            <div
              class=" p-0"
              style={{ width: "11.11%" }}
              onClick={() => this.handleMoreTheme()}
            >
              <div class="th-cat-link ">
                <img alt=" " src={E1} class="fluid-image" />
                <p class="th-cat-name">
                  {this.state.isMore ? "Less Theme" : "More Theme"}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `slice` to take only 8 and the check if the length is more than 8 display the button

```
{
     this.props.categoryData.slice(0,8).map((data) => (
              <div class=" p-0" style={{ width: "12%" }}>
                <div class="th-cat-link">
                  <img
                    alt=" "
                    src={data.photo_desktop}
                    width="50"
                    class="fluid-image"
                  />
                  <p class="th-cat-name">{data.package_category_name}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
}
{
     this.props.categoryData.length > 8 && <button>Show More</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ali for your response. I want to add the remaining items in new row after onClick event on Show More. How to add new row?

Comment: you can store the value of `8` in the state and when the button called you double that state, so you will do this, let's call that value `displaySize` for example

`this.props.categoryData.slice(0,this.state.displaySize).map(...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.categoryData.map((data) => (
          <div class=" p-0" style={{ width: "12%" }}>
            <div class="th-cat-link">
              <img
                alt=" "
                src={data.photo_desktop}
                width="50"
                class="fluid-image"
              />
              <p class="th-cat-name">{data.package_category_name}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        {this.props.categoryData.length > 8 && <button>Show More</button>}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default App
```